# Interpretation of indirect effect in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, simultaneous-equation

[image: direct and indirect effects]

Ancillary units have lesser probability of accessing formal finance (-0.027). But, through profitability, the indirect effect Ancillary unit has on Formal Funding is positive and significant at 1% level (0.072*0.481 = 0.035).

Ancillary unit is a dummy variable coded one if the firm is ancillary and coded zero otherwise. Profitability is a continuous variable. Formal funding is a dummy variable coded one if firm has formal funding and coded zero if the firm does not have formal funding

Please help me interpret this result.

Comment: This model is not identified. You cannot estimate cyclic paths without restrictions, and this is a fully saturated model. There are three covariances between the variables but you estimated four path coefficients. Please talk more about how you estimated the model (e.g., with code if available) because as it stands, this model doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is just a part of the model in the interpretation of which I am interested in.  I have other variables including instrumental variables in the model.